# Использование returning с последующим insert

Tags: postgresql

В PostgreSQL (версии 10) я делаю некоторый `insert` с разрешением конфликта в виде `update` и возвращаю `id`. Можно ли и, если можно, то как использовать этот `id` для `insert` в одном sql-запросе? Т.е. я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде такого:

```
WITH someVal AS (
    INSERT INTO someTable01
    (col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES(val1, val2, val3) ON CONFLICT (val1, val2) DO UPDATE
    SET val1=someVal1, val2=someVal2, val3=someVal3
    RETURNING id
) INSERT INTO someTable02 (otherCol1, otherCol2, fkCol3)
VALUES(otherVal1, otherVal2, (select id from someVal));
```

Колонки в таблицах разные. Во второй таблице собственно есть `foreign key` на `id` первой таблицы, который я и хочу использовать вернув из выражения вставки\обновления.

Comment: А что собственно происходит, фореджен ругается что записи нет ? У меня есть подозрение, что в таких конструкциях когда внешний запрос выполняется запись вставленная внутренним еще не до конца существует.

Comment: Я не уверен, что такая логика вообще возможна, просто нигде не нашёл явного упоминания использования `returning` в таком ключе, хотя вроде кажется вполне логичным. Суть в том, чтобы не делать явный дополнительный `select`.

Comment: теоретически оно вполне возможно было бы, если запись вставленная внутренним запросом была бы видна. вместо второго insert сделайте select from someTable01 where id in(select id from someVal). И увидите забавную вещь, если запись уже существовала и выполнялся по сути update - то запрос вернет строку. А если записи не было - то запрос ничего не вернет, потому что запись еще не вставлена окончательно

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Получается дополнительный `select` сделать всё таки придётся.